# Does Russia's veto at the UN Security Council end any role for the United Nations in investigating the alleged chemical weapons attack in Syria?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, united-nations, syria, chemical-weapons

This afternoon, a resolution at the UN Security Council, aimed to establish an independent investigation into alleged chemical weapons attacks in Syria, was vetoed by Russia.

Is there a way that the 12 members who voted in favour of the resolution to insist upon it, for example by escalating it to the General Assembly?  Is there any alternative way that the UN could investigate these allegations despite this veto?   Or is this the definitive end of any UN involvement in the matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does Russia's veto at the UN Security Council end any role for the United Nations in investigating the alleged chemical weapons attack in Syria?

Yes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_veto_power

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vetoed_United_Nations_Security_Council_resolutions

> Is there a way that the 12 members who voted in favour of the resolution to insist upon it, for example by escalating it to the General Assembly? Is there any alternative way that the UN could investigate these allegations despite this veto? Or is this the definitive end of any UN involvement in the matter?

It is the definitive end of any UN involvement in the matter, until another resolution is put forward.